# insert multiple same field name codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```html
<input name="fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1023456789" value="">

<input name="fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1023456789" value="">

<input name="fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1023456789" value="">

<input name="fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1023456789" value="">
```

**how to insert this value using codeigniter *

Comment: What code you have tried so far?

Comment: if you `print_r($this->input->post('fldWorkHistoryCompanyName')` it should become readily apparent how this type of post variable is represented. it's just an array.

Answer (score 2):

The superglobal `$_POST['fldWorkHistoryCompanyName']` will be an array where each value is the contents of the text inputs. Capture the array and loop through it doing what you need to do.

```
$names = $this->input->post('fldWorkHistoryCompanyName');
foreach ($names as $name)
{
    if(empty($name))
    {
        // whatever you need to do when no data was sent
        // if you want to ignore empty inputs then all you need is
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        //save $name to the database
    }
```

Comment: $data2[] = array(
            'fldUserID' => $insert_id,
            'fldWorkHistoryCompanyName' => $this->input->post('fldWorkHistoryCompanyName')
         
        );$this->db->insert_batch('tblWorkHistory', $data2);  error massage in undefined array

Comment: $data3 = array();
        $fldWorkHistoryCompanyName[] = $this->input->post('fldWorkHistoryCompanyName');
foreach ($fldWorkHistoryCompanyName as $value) {
    
    $data3[] = array(
        
        'fldUserID' => $insert_id,
        'fldWorkHistoryCompanyName' => $value
    );
    //var_dump($this->db->insert('tblWorkHistory',$data3));die();
    $this->db->insert('tblWorkHistory',$data3); 
}    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0) VALUES (Array)' at line 1